# Imagemagick: how to convert images with different size to image 1920x1080 (white background)

Tags: image-processing, command-line, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I've a folder with several images with different size (i.e. 1284x456, 1290x445 and so on...).
I need to convert each image to 1920x1080px:

1. enlarging the sizes proportionally so that I have them 1920px large (i.e. 1920x681, 1920x662 and so on...);
2. and then adding a white background so that the final height of the output image becomes exactly 1080px (with the old image vertically centered).

Is it possible with a single command?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think that I found the trick:

```
for i in *.jpg; do convert -resize 1920x1080 -gravity center -background white -extent 1920x1080 $i `basename $i `.JPG; done
```